# Как редактировать несколько изображений?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть `input`, который добавляет несколько изображений.
Потом я вывожу 5 из них, которые загрузил.
Как мне правильно редактировать одно или два изображения из пяти?
Одно я делал, а вот как редактировать несколько?

```html
 public function editImg(Request $request)
    {
        $req = $request->all();
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($request['photo']); $i++) {
                $photo = $request->file('photo')[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
                $file_ext = explode('.', $photo);
                $file_ext = end($file_ext);
                $file_name_new = microtime() . '.' . $file_ext;
                $destination = base_path() . '/public/img';
                $request->file('photo')[$i]->move($destination, $file_name_new);

                $photo = Image::find($req['id']);
                //$photo->id = $req["id"];
                $photo->images = $file_name_new;
                $photo->save();
            }
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: ну так попробуйте сами а потом если не получиться приложите код, а так подсказка циклы

Comment: Я код добавил как делаю, но записывает только первую, а потому что id = 1 а потому и первая )